# HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync not getting idsrv cookie from new google oauth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth, identityserver4, google-identity

I've a SSO based on IDS4. When migrating to new Google Identity Services, I'm successfully getting idsrv.session cookie when I'm Google authenticating from my other app which uses the SSO. But when I tried logging in from my SSO, I don't get the idsrv.session cookie.

Here's my gsi frontend :

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

                                        <div id="g_id_onload"
                                             data-client_id="ClientID"
                                             data-login_uri="CallbackURI" //GoogleCallback uri.
                                             data-auto_prompt="false"
                                             data-context="signin"
                                             data-ux_mode="popup">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="g_id_signin"
                                             data-type="standard"
                                             data-size="large"
                                             data-theme="outline"
                                             data-text="sign_in_with"
                                             data-shape="rectangular"
                                             data-logo_alignment="left">
                                        </div>
```

Here's the GoogleCallback method :

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleCallback( GoogleSignInFormData data)
        {
            
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
            if (result?.Succeeded != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("External authentication error");
            }


            // validate the JWT token from Google
            var googleValidationResult = await ValidateGoogleTokenAsync(data.credential);
            if (googleValidationResult is null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Google JWT Token is null.");
            }

            // read external identity from the temporary cookie
            var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");

            // lookup our user and external provider info
            var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = await FindUserFromExternalProviderAsync(result, googleValidationResult);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { error = "We didn't find any user account with above email address." });
            }

            // this allows us to collect any additional claims or properties
            // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
            // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
            var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
            _userService.UpdateUserAgencyClaim(user.Id);
            UserClaimModel userClaim = userClaimService.Get(user.Id);
            if (userClaim.ClaimType.ToLower() == "agencies")
                additionalLocalClaims.Add(new Claim("agencies", userClaim.ClaimValue));
            var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
            //ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

            // issue authentication cookie for user
            var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
            {
                DisplayName = user.UserName,
                IdentityProvider = provider,
                AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
            };


            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);

            // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            // retrieve return URL
            //var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";
            var returnUrl = "~/";

            // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
            await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.Id, user.UserName, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

            if (context != null)
            {
                if (context.IsNativeClient())
                {
                    // The client is native, so this change in how to
                    // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                    return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);
                }
            }

            return Redirect(returnUrl);



        }
```

I tried everything possible to my knowledge. I dont get why is it not working in my SSO but is working when i'm calling it from my other app that uses the SSO. P.S. The frontend is same in both the app i.e.,  SSO and Client app. and both points the same callback.